# copyTo Google Sheets Script for openByUrl, with a URL from a list

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am very new to Javascript and Apps Script. I want to create a function that updates another sheet based on a date in a certain range of the active sheet. I run and no error but it doesn't transfer value from active sheet to sheet named "Master", in different target url google sheet

[data master post](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jQ93ylP0MHzSzxH0myS9_AhTjetdvLQMXvFwg18XFEE/edit#gid=0)

[output 1](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ShPxDW9qhz4aWgaQ1G9oz7w1yh0-Wfe2VItet95UYks/edit?usp=sharing)

[output 2](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13Dx3ZOpV7baSTadSApIrVVccN-bHrPlHu240Aux0fo0/edit?usp=sharing)

[output 3](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14EVlqaP1ilXwopgi0ESvp_IKkSyROSF22WzWAcNAJWc/edit?usp=sharing)

```
function updateYTD4() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName("January");
  const targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Master");
  if (sheet && targetSheet) {
    if(sheet.getRange("A2:D32").getValues().length > 0){
      sheet.getRange("A2:D32").copyTo(targetSheet.getRange("C"+(targetSheet.getLastRow()+1)),{contentsOnly:true});
    }
  }
}
```

I want master data, can post/send data to output 1, output 2, output 3, to each sheetname?

```
function open_by_url() {
  var urls = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("B2:B4").getValues();
  console.log(urls)
  for (var i in urls) {
    var url = urls[i][0];
    console.log(url);
    var s = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
    console.log(s.getName());
  }
}
```

I try but error

```
function updateYTD5() {
  const urls = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("D1:F3").getValues();
  const sourceSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName("January");
  const targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Master");
  if (sheet && targetSheet) {
    if(sheet.getRange("A2:D32").getValues().length > 0){
      sheet.getRange("A2:D32").copyTo(targetSheet.getRange("C"+(targetSheet.getLastRow()+1)),{contentsOnly:true});
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I saw your sample Spreadsheet, I couldn't find "Master" sheet. But, from your script, I guessed that you might copy each row of the "January" sheet to 1st tab of each Spreadsheet. If my understanding is correct, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

In this case, please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of "data master post" spreadsheet.

```js
function sample() {
  // Retrieve Sheet object.
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("January");

  // Retrieve values from cells "A2:F".
  const values = sheet.getRange("A2:F" + sheet.getLastRow()).getValues();

  // By using the Spreadsheet URL of column "B", the values of columns "D" to "F" are appended to the 1st sheet of each Spreadsheet.
  values.forEach(([, url, , ...v]) => {
    const dstSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url).getSheets()[0];
    dstSheet.appendRow(v);
  });
}
```

- In this sample script, the values are retrieved from the "January" sheet. And, using the spreadsheet URL retrieved from the column "B", the values from columns "D" to "F" are copied to the 1st tab of Spreadsheet of each spreadsheet url.
- From your provided sample Spreadsheet, I guessed that in order to copy a row, `appendRow` might be useful.

#### References:

- [forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)
- [appendRow(rowContents)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet?hl=ja#appendRow(Object))

### Added:

As another sample script, how about the following sample script? The result of this script is the same as the above script.

#### Sample script:

```js
function sample2() {
  // Retrieve Sheet object.
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("January");

  // Retrieve values from cells "A2:F".
  const values = sheet.getRange("A2:F" + sheet.getLastRow()).getValues();

  // By using the Spreadsheet URL of column "B", the values of columns "D" to "F" are appended to the 1st sheet of each Spreadsheet.
  for (let i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    const dstSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(values[i][1]).getSheets()[0];
    dstSheet.appendRow([values[i][3], values[i][4], values[i][5]]);
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand, can you give the above case my script code above, Tanaike

Comment: @dra Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your current issue in my answer from `I don't understand, can you give the above case my script code above, Tanaike –`. Can I ask you about the detail of `the above case my script code above`? By correctly understanding your current issue, I would like to modify the answer. I deeply apologize that I am trying to correctly understand your question.

Comment: @dra From your question, I understood your question as follows. You want to retrieve the URLs of the Spreadsheet from "data master post" spreadsheet. And, you want to retrieve each row and copy and paste them to 1st tab in each spreadsheet. Is my understanding of your question correct? If my understanding is not correct, I apologize. At that time, can I ask you about the detail of your actual expected result? By this, I would like to confirm it. I deeply apologize for my very poor English skill, again. If you can cooperate to resolve your question, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it?

Comment: you want to retrieve each row and copy and paste them to 1st tab in each spreadsheet. yes. >>>> values.forEach(([, url, , ...v]) => {     , how use that.  sorry my language uses translate.google.co.id .    
Tanaike

Comment: @dra Thank you for replying. About `you want to retrieve each row and copy and paste them to the 1st tab in each spreadsheet. yes.`, I understood that my understanding of your question was correct. And, my answer achieves this. When you use this script, please copy and paste my script to the script editor of "data master post" spreadsheet. And run `sample()`. By this, the script works. In this case, I tested my script using your provided Spreadsheet. Please be careful about this.

Comment: @dra About the script, now, I added some comments to my script. If these comments are not useful, I apologize again.

Comment: @dra About `values.forEach(([, url, , ...v]) => {,,,})`, here, each value from the columns is retrieved by the destructuring assignment. [Ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) In this case, `url` is column "B". `..v` is the values from columns "D" to "F". `...` is the spread syntax. [Ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) If this explanation was not useful, I apologize again.

Comment: @dra Now, I added one more sample script. Will that help to understand the script? If that was not useful, I apologize again.